# relationship between forward and backward error?

Tags: numerical-methods

Let $\tilde{f} $ be some algorithm: we have:
$$ \| f(x) - \tilde{f}(x) \| = \| f(x) - f(\tilde{x}) \| \leq \|f'(x) \| \|x - \tilde{x} \|$$

I'm curious on the last step, how did they get the inequality? It kind of looks like the mean value theorem but f' is dependent on x and not on some variable between x and $\tilde{x}$ so I don't think it's that

thanks

Comment: This does not make sense. Define $f(x)=x^2$.  Define $x=0$, $\tilde{x}=1$.  Then $|f(x)-f(\tilde{x})|=1$, but $|f'(x)||x-\tilde{x}| = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the vector version of the mean value theorem says
$$
\|f(x)-f(\bar x)\|\le \sup_{z\in [x,\bar x]}\|f'(z)\|·\|x-\bar x\|
$$
where $[x,\bar x]$ is the line segment between the points.

Perhaps the intended meaning was that this holds to first order, i.e.,
$$
\|f(x)-f(\bar x)\|\le \|f'(x)\|·\|x-\bar x\|+O(\|x-\bar x\|^2).
$$
In the numerical error analysis, one often only considers the first order terms of the error, as when the relative difference $\|x-\bar x\|\sim\mu·\|x\|$ is a small (or even medium large) multiple of the constant of machine precision, the second order effects fall far below machine precision, thus do not influence the floating point result.